# Engadget like menu - font not matching

Tags: css

I am trying to create a menu bar like [Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/). I seem to implement it properly but still I am not getting the exact font style. Please help me out. Thanks.
Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UMfe/).

My HTML,

```
<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Reviews</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

​
My CSS,

```
 .nav{
        background:#303030;
        line-height:1;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:relative; 
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;

}

.nav a{
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;        
        font-family: Oswald,Arial Narrow,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
        text-transform:uppercase !important;
        font-size:14px !important;
        margin-right:10px;
        padding:10px;
        display: block;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-weight:lighter;

}
.nav li{
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden
}
.nav ul{
        list-style:none;
        margin:0;
        overflow:hidden;
        padding:0;
        width:100%
}
.nav ul a:hover
{
        color:#FFF;
        background-color:#454545 !important;                     
}
.nav ul,nav ol
{
        list-style:none;
        list-style-image:none
}
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must import resp. link the font!
In the css of the Engadget you can see it in the style css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Oswald";
    src: url("http ...
```

I updated it as example: http://jsfiddle.net/5UMfe/2/

Comment: see Andy's answer for details ;)

Comment: +1 for the `@font-face` rule, although you may run into issues with older browsers like IE8.  Using the @import method for Google web fonts can save that extra hassle.

Comment: To get details about using Google Web Fonts look here: 
https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/getting_started.
There you can also find some examples.

Answer (score 2):

Engadget use an open web font named **Oswald**.  You didn't include it in your source, but it is [available on Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Oswald).

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300);
```

Here's [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UMfe/1/).

Comment: ...and another updated [fiddle with valid HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/5UMfe/3/) that makes the result a bit better.